# How should I approach porting a device driver to OS X?

Tags: macos, kernel, driver

I am thinking about migrating a Windows driver into OS X. Now I am just starting to look around to see what is available and there is a lot about objective C and cocoa. Seems that the language and the cocoa framework are high level APIs, am I right to assume that?

I have strong C++ skills and I use them for kernel development, can I use the same skills for Mac driver development (I imagine the answer is yes). Has Macintosh any type of application/dev environment for building drivers?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [Apple Hardware & Drivers page](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/HardwareDrivers/index.html) has lots of information about Mac driver development. It should be enough to get you started. Some of the highlights:

- [**Getting Started**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_HardwareDrivers/_index.html) - A guided learning path for hardware and driver developers new to Mac OS X.
- [**Frameworks**](http://developer.apple.com/referencelibrary/API_Fundamentals/HardwareDrivers-api-date.html) - API references organized by framework.
- [**USB Sample Code**](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/HardwareDrivers/idxUSB-date.html) - Resources for developing USB devices and software to access them.
- [**FireWire Sample Code**](http://developer.apple.com/samplecode/HardwareDrivers/idxFireWire-date.html) - Resources for developing FireWire devices and software to access them.

Answer (score 1):

Start here http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/About/About.html

Mac development is generally done using Xcode, as it handles various Mac-specific concepts like bundles and frameworks.  You will most likely be working in pure C.  You will not be using Cocoa for driver development, as that is an application-oriented framework.

Answer (score 0):

First, C++ works just fine, although Objective C is not all that hard to learn. If you have a background in Windows drivers you know some of the essentials- memory management is critical, time is critical, etc.

You will probably be using the IOKit.  I suggest starting here for a good, step by step intro to getting the driver to work.

[Kernel Extensions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KEXTConcept/KEXTConceptIntro/introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000191-SW1)

There are a few things that don't seem to work the way they say they will, and I'm trying to figure out if it really is not possible to debug a driver on a single machine, but it's better than most Apple documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you're targeting Catalina or higher, you should also consider [DriverKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/driverkit).