# How can I access the Ethernet port's I/O on a hardware level in Mac OS X?

Tags: c, macos, ethernet

My specific interest is in controlling the Ethernet port's 8 pins to send signals. How can I achieve this in C on a Mac? What headers will I need?

Comment: Everything you need should need to get started should answered in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001374/mac-driver-development. Not sure about the duplicate nature. That question is more general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible (and likely) that the individual outputs are controlled entirely by hardware from a frame buffer (Ethernet frame, not the video kind), and that unless your card has an explicit mode to allow you to use them as GPIO (which is probably rather rare) you're not going to have much luck, even with a custom driver.

Answer (score 0):

From this [Kernel Extension Programming Topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001374/mac-driver-development/1001403#1001403)

> A kernel extension (or kext) is a dynamically loaded bundle of
>   executable code that runs in kernel space. You can create a kext to
>   perform low-level tasks that cannot be performed in user space. Kexts
>   typically belong to one of three categories:
>
> - Low-level device drivers
> - Network filters
> - File systems 
>     This document is
>     a primary resource for kext programming in Mac OS X. It describes the
>     structure of a kext and demonstrates the process for developing a
>     kext, from creating an Xcode project to packaging your kext for
>     distribution.

(I'm putting this here as I think this question needs a pointer to the answers in [Mac driver development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001374/mac-driver-development) but with a little more context than closed as a dup)

Comment: that's out of my calibre for now =/ is there anything like outb for ethernet? (i've previously used it for parallel port programming on ubuntu)

Comment: Sorry my driver programming knowledge is restricted to windows.

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX: Depends on the controller, but the answer is most likely no.